# Recursive query with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I need some help with one query.
So, I already have CTE with the next data:

| ApplicationID | CandidateId | JobId | Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

I need to find one job per candidate in a way, that this job was distinct for table.

I expect that next data from query (for each candidate select the first available jobid that's not taken by the previous candidate):

| ApplicationID | CandidateId | JobId | Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 6 | 2 |

I have never worked with recursive queries in CTE, having read about them, to be honest, I don't fully understand how this can be applied in my case. I ask for help in this regard.

Comment: I don't really understand on which basis are you selecting your data? As far as I can tell you want unique CandidateID, but what is the criteria to selecting rest of the values?

Comment: JobId=1 is not unique, why it should be in the output?

Comment: @ahmed i'm thinking in the way, that when we  will select to result set the first row, there will be CandidateId = 1 and JobId = 1, ok, then we move to another candidate  (CandidateId = 2), if we will take his first row (where JobId = 1) and put it in the result set there will be duplication between JobId's. So we need to take JobId from another row (for CandidateId = 2) to escape duplication. If there won't be unique Jobid, don't select this candidate.

Comment: So, why you chose JobId=5 for the second candidate? why it's not JobId=2?

Comment: @ahmed sorry, my typo, there should be JobId  = 2

Comment: So, for each candidate select the first available jobid that's not taken by the previous candidate, is that correct?

Comment: @ahmed absolutely

Comment: I think here is a small glitch in the idea: according to your description, candidate 3 should receive job 3 since it is neither used by candidate 1 nor by candidate 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the expected result.

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ApplicationID) N,
    CONVERT(varchar(max), CONCAT(',',JobId,',')) Jobs
    FROM ApplicationCandidateCTE
    ORDER BY ApplicationID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.ApplicationID),
    CONCAT(Jobs,a.JobId,',') Jobs
    FROM ApplicationCandidateCTE a JOIN CTE b
    ON a.ApplicationID > b.ApplicationID AND
       a.CandidateId > b.CandidateId AND
       CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',',a.JobId,','), b.Jobs)=0 AND
       b.N = 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE N = 1;
```

However, I have the following concerns:

- The recursive CTE may extract too many rows.
- The concatenated JobId may exceed varchar(max).

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JFwaTagZ).

Comment: yes, and please correct me if i'm wrong, this query guarantee, that in result set will be distinct candidate id and job for whole table?

Comment: Each CandidateId and JobId is unique. The CandidateId is greater than any previous row by the condition `a.CandidateId > b.CandidateId`. The same value of JobId doesn't exist before that row by the condition `a.JobId <> b.JobId`.

Comment: thank you so much, now it's look clear and i start understand more about this.

Comment: not sure this makes sense... `a.CandidateId > b.CandidateId`. it gives for granted that candidates are sorted ascending, generally speaking, I don't see how that can be the case in real case scenario, in which I expect candidates to apply in any order

Comment: @etsuhisa however, is there an option here without using recursion?

Comment: Sorry. My query doesn't work correctly. I try to fix the query, but I couldn't find out. Please unaccept it.

Comment: @Facade Fixed the query. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JFwaTagZ). However, the recursive CTE extracts too many rows. So I'm concerned about poor performance.

Comment: @etsuhisa so can i accept you current answer? is there a correct variant? And why your first variant wasn't correct? For me it's return expected result.

Comment: @Facade I have rewritten my answer. The previous query did not find the JobId correctly. I think this query will give the expected result.

Comment: @etsuhisa can you please explain, why previous query did not find the JobId correctly?

Comment: @Facade `a.JobId <> b.JobId` is incorrect. It returns JobIds that have already appeared. It should be like `a.JobId NOT IN (SELECT b.JobId FROM CTE)` but a subquery is not allowed in CTE. So, I changed the concatenated JobId (`CONCAT(Jobs,a.JobId,',') Jobs`) to look for the next JobId (`CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',',a.JobId,','), b.Jobs)=0`).